# iOS- Not working sonar script 'run-sonar-swift'

Tags: ios, swift, sonarqube

I am trying to implement sonar qube swift. I have installed all prerequisites setup that you can find in the link.

https://medium.com/@pranay.urkude/sonarqube-integration-with-ios-b76df8405014

But when i run the **./run-sonar-swift.sh -v** command then getting the error. which is mention in below logs please

```
>Apples-MacBook-Air:Wanna Aman$ ./run-sonar-swift.sh -v
Running run-sonar-swift.sh...
Project count is [1]
Xcode project file is: Wanna.xcodeproj
Xcode workspace file is: Wanna.xcworkspace
Xcode application scheme is: Wanna
Number version from plist is: 1.0
Destination simulator is: platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=12.2
Excluded paths from coverage are: 
Creating directory sonar-reports/
Extracting Xcode project information
+ xcodebuild clean build -workspace Wanna.xcworkspace -scheme Wanna -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=12.2' -destination-timeout 360 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO
+ returnValue=0
+ set +x
▸ Clean Succeeded
▸ Copying Pods-Wanna-umbrella.h
▸ Processing Pods-Wanna-Info.plist
▸ Compiling Pods-Wanna-dummy.m
▸ Compiling Pods_Wanna_vers.c
▸ Touching Pods_Wanna.framework (in target: Pods-Wanna)
▸ Running script '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock'
▸ Compiling ViewController.swift
▸ Compiling AppDelegate.swift
▸ Linking Wanna
▸ Compiling LaunchScreen.storyboard
▸ Compiling Main.storyboard
▸ Processing Info.plist
▸ Touching Wanna.app (in target: Wanna)
▸ Build Succeeded
actual = 9549, min = 3
Running surefire
+ xcodebuild clean build test -workspace Wanna.xcworkspace -scheme Wanna -configuration Debug -enableCodeCoverage YES -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=12.2' -destination-timeout 60
2019-07-01 17:00:18.123 xcodebuild[34637:171741]  IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test session to:
/Users/Aman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wanna-flozsuddkzcjfadhlxefzthqazgq/Logs/Test/Run-Wanna-2019.07.01_17-00-12-+0530.xcresult/3_Test/Diagnostics/WannaTests-DACAF56A-03C3-43EA-AEF4-BF18730C5266/WannaTests-13AB698C-A67D-4AB5-92FF-A0F03008C70D/Session-WannaTests-2019-07-01_170018-25708T.log
2019-07-01 17:00:18.124 xcodebuild[34637:171579] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (86CE27D3-0AD7-4F62-B501-A3EB8862A636) Beginning test session WannaTests-86CE27D3-0AD7-4F62-B501-A3EB8862A636 at 2019-07-01 17:00:18.124 with Xcode 10E1001 on target <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7fdd68da7af0> {
        SimDevice: iPhone 7 (763FCF55-E246-4DC4-9240-91D57CED4F0A, iOS 12.2, Shutdown)
} (12.2 (16E226))
2019-07-01 17:00:28.099 xcodebuild[34637:171579] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (86CE27D3-0AD7-4F62-B501-A3EB8862A636) Finished requesting crash reports. Continuing with testing.
2019-07-01 17:00:40.206 xcodebuild[34637:171675]  IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test session to:
/Users/Aman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wanna-flozsuddkzcjfadhlxefzthqazgq/Logs/Test/Run-Wanna-2019.07.01_17-00-12-+0530.xcresult/3_Test/Diagnostics/WannaUITests-9971F8D3-0217-4F89-B28E-AF6745AC64E6/WannaUITests-2DC182C8-A11E-4D24-897F-C2F8F6D2D86F/Session-WannaUITests-2019-07-01_170040-45gLHX.log
2019-07-01 17:00:40.206 xcodebuild[34637:171579] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (273A8001-66F3-469C-9A45-E7B689DF080A) Beginning test session WannaUITests-273A8001-66F3-469C-9A45-E7B689DF080A at 2019-07-01 17:00:40.206 with Xcode 10E1001 on target <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7fdd68da7af0> {
        SimDevice: iPhone 7 (763FCF55-E246-4DC4-9240-91D57CED4F0A, iOS 12.2, Booted)
} (12.2 (16E226))
2019-07-01 17:00:40.461 xcodebuild[34637:171579] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (273A8001-66F3-469C-9A45-E7B689DF080A) Finished requesting crash reports. Continuing with testing.
2019-07-01 17:00:58.421 xcodebuild[34637:171579] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 40.317 elapsed -- Testing started completed.
2019-07-01 17:00:58.421 xcodebuild[34637:171579] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.000 sec, +0.000 sec -- start
2019-07-01 17:00:58.421 xcodebuild[34637:171579] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 40.317 sec, +40.317 sec -- end
+ returnValue=0
+ set +x
.T.  Executed 2 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.542 (0.545) seconds
     Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 9.052 (9.056) seconds
\nComputing coverage report\n
>Command line exclusion flags for slather is:
slather coverage --binary-basename Wanna --input-format profdata --cobertura-xml --output-directory sonar-reports --workspace Wanna.xcworkspace --scheme Wanna Wanna.xcodeproj
+ slather coverage --binary-basename Wanna --input-format profdata --cobertura-xml --output-directory sonar-reports --workspace Wanna.xcworkspace --scheme Wanna Wanna.xcodeproj
Slathering...
Slathered
+ returnValue=0
+ set +x
Running SwiftLint...dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/swiftlint
  Reason: image not found
./run-sonar-swift.sh: line 384: 34914 Abort trap: 6           $SWIFTLINT_CMD lint --path "$word" > sonar-reports/"$appScheme"-swiftlint.txt
Running Tailor...Running OCLint...
Path included in oclint analysis is: --include .*/Wanna/Wanna/*
+ oclint-json-compilation-database -v --include ../Wanna/Wanna/AppDelegate.swift ../Wanna/Wanna/Assets.xcassets ../Wanna/Wanna/Base.lproj ../Wanna/Wanna/Info.plist ../Wanna/Wanna/ViewController.swift -- -rc LONG_LINE=250 -max-priority-1 10000 -max-priority-2 10000 -max-priority-3 10000 -report-type pmd -o sonar-reports/Wanna-oclint.xml
------------------------------ OCLint ------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/oclint -p /Users/Aman/Desktop/Wanna ../Wanna/Wanna/Assets.xcassets ../Wanna/Wanna/Base.lproj ../Wanna/Wanna/Info.plist ../Wanna/Wanna/ViewController.swift -rc LONG_LINE=250 -max-priority-1 10000 -max-priority-2 10000 -max-priority-3 10000 -report-type pmd -o sonar-reports/Wanna-oclint.xml
--------------------------------------------------------------------
>Skipping /Users/Aman/Desktop/Wanna/../Wanna/Wanna/Assets.xcassets. Compile command not found.
Skipping /Users/Aman/Desktop/Wanna/../Wanna/Wanna/Base.lproj. Compile command not found.
Skipping /Users/Aman/Desktop/Wanna/../Wanna/Wanna/Info.plist. Compile command not found.
Skipping /Users/Aman/Desktop/Wanna/../Wanna/Wanna/ViewController.swift. Compile command not found.
+ returnValue=0
+ set +x
Running FauxPas...Determining build settings for 3 targets and 2 build configurations
The Xcode project format is "Xcode 9.3". Faux Pas supports Xcode projects that are Xcode 8.0 or 6.3 or 3.2 or 3.1 -compatible. Some features may not work correctly.
Checking project: Wanna
          target: Wanna
   configuration: Release
         ruleset: 86 Rules tagged [Recommended]: UndetachedDelegate, InvalidStringsFile, StringsFileEncoding, UIKitKVO, UnnecessaryNullCheck, RetinaImagesResolution, AssertionSideEffects, SuspiciousResources, NullCoalescingOp, LoadMethodWithoutAutoreleasePool, UnknownResourceCodeReference, StringsdictWithoutStrings, InitializeSuperInvocation, UnsupportedWeakReference, CompilerWarnings, HardcodedUIString, HardcodedSelfClass, MacroBasedIncludeGuard, RestrictedDirectMethodCall, RecommendedVCSIgnores, RetainingImmutableProperty, MissingAPIUsageDescription, CompleteNotificationCenterDetachment, XIBRuntimeAttributeMismatch, ThreadUnsafeInstanceCaching, MissingTranslation, RestrictedMethodOverride, MissingDeviceTypeResource, OldVerboseObjCSyntax, ViewLayoutInXIB, IsEqualAndHash, FileRefOutsideVCS, LiteralStringKeyPath, BasicProjectSettings, DuplicateTranslation, StrongDelegate, ConstructorReturnType, SetterInvocationInInitOrDealloc, ArgumentModification, FastEnumElementOutside, UnusedErrorValue, CopyingMutableProperty, ImplicitBundleId, UnnecessaryNibMethod, AssociatedObjectOnValueType, OrderedPointerToZeroComparison, PrefixHeaderIncludeSuggestion, ReleaseBuildCompilerArgs, XcconfigOverwrites, BuildSettingSelfReference, BuildSettingPlacement, FixedFormatDateFormatter, TerminatingApp, AbsPathInBuildSetting, PrivateCategory, FileRefWithAbsPath, MissingImageResolutionVariant, TranslationPunctuation, WeakReferenceToTopLevelXIBObject, UnprefixedClass, InitializeMethodCategoryOverride, SuspiciousDateTimeFormat, ReleaseBuildConfig, AssigningDelegate, UnknownResourceXIBReference, GlobalAndLocalizedResource, UnknownResourceModifier, Swizzling, ZeroAssignmentToPointer, DiscardedOpaqueNotificationObserver, DylibInstallName, TranslationFormatMismatch, SuspiciousMissingResources, ErrorConditionCheck, RedundantInclude, ReservedPrefix, NSLogUsed, UnprefixedCategoryMethod, UnidiomaticAccessorNaming, UncommentedLocalizedString, DuplicateResource, ViewControllerInitWithNibName, CategoryMethodConflict, BlockAPIRetainCycle, FileRefIgnoredInVCS, MissingNotificationCenterDetachment
Trial Version: Delaying operation for 15 more seconds…
Trial Version: Delaying operation for 14 more seconds…
Trial Version: Delaying operation for 13 more seconds…
Trial Version: Delaying operation for 12 more seconds…
Trial Version: Delaying operation for 11 more seconds…
Trial Version: Delaying operation for 10 more seconds…
Trial Version: Delaying operation for 9 more seconds…
Trial Version: Delaying operation for 8 more seconds…
Trial Version: Delaying operation for 7 more seconds…
Trial Version: Delaying operation for 6 more seconds…
Trial Version: Delaying operation for 5 more seconds…
Trial Version: Delaying operation for 4 more seconds…
Trial Version: Delaying operation for 3 more seconds…
Trial Version: Delaying operation for 2 more seconds…
Trial Version: Delaying operation for 1 more seconds…
Initialization: Determining VCS state...
Initialization: Resolving build settings...
Rule InvalidStringsFile will not be applied: “Applies to localized projects.”
Rule StringsFileEncoding will not be applied: “Applies to projects under Git version control.”
Rule LoadMethodWithoutAutoreleasePool will not be applied: “Applies to projects targeting an OS prior to iOS 6 or Mac OS 10.8.”
Rule StringsdictWithoutStrings will not be applied: “Applies to localized projects.”
Rule UnsupportedWeakReference will not be applied: “Applies to OS X targets.”
Rule HardcodedUIString will not be applied: “Applies to localized projects.”
Rule RecommendedVCSIgnores will not be applied: “Applies to projects under Git version control.”
Rule MissingTranslation will not be applied: “Applies to localized projects.”
Rule FileRefOutsideVCS will not be applied: “Applies to projects using one of these version control systems: Git, Mercurial, Bazaar, Subversion, Fossil.”
Rule DuplicateTranslation will not be applied: “Applies to localized projects.”
Rule PrefixHeaderIncludeSuggestion will not be applied: “Applies to projects that use a prefix header, and have at least 10 source code files.”
Rule TranslationPunctuation will not be applied: “Applies to localized projects.”
Rule DylibInstallName will not be applied: “Applies to OS X targets.”
Rule TranslationFormatMismatch will not be applied: “Applies to localized projects.”
Rule RedundantInclude will not be applied: “Applies to projects using a prefix header.”
Rule UncommentedLocalizedString will not be applied: “Applies to localized projects.”
Rule FileRefIgnoredInVCS will not be applied: “Applies to projects under Git version control.”
Rule MissingNotificationCenterDetachment will not be applied: “Applies to projects targeting an OS prior to iOS 9 or Mac OS 10.11.”
Initialization: Performing full build: required because project contains Swift code
Initialization: Building the project
Initialization: Processing build steps
ERROR: Initialization: Could not determine build steps for specified target 'Wanna'
Preparation failed → clearing build log caches
Checked total 0 code statements in 00:00:24.871 (the preparation took 00:00:09.792 (39.4%)).
Total 0 diagnostics.
(Evaluation trial limitation: only 5 random diagnostics will be returned when using machine-readable output.)
Some errors were encountered. If these are a problem, please consider the following remedies:
• Just try again — the project caches have now been cleared
• If source files are generated during builds, or if interpreting this project's source code otherwise depends on full builds to occur, enable the 'Build project before checking' option.
• In general, ensure that the xcodebuild arguments Faux Pas uses are correct: enable the 'verbose' option and try performing the checks to see what arguments are being used, and then determine if they need to be adjusted
Running Lizard...Running SonarQube using SonarQube Runner
+ sonar-scanner --define sonar.projectVersion=1.0
./run-sonar-swift.sh: line 101: sonar-scanner: command not found
+ returnValue=127
+ set +x
ERROR - Command 'sonar-scanner --define sonar.projectVersion=1.0' failed with error code: 127
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you solve it @Aman?

Comment: Yeah solved @SazzadHissainKhan

Comment: @AmanPathak can you post your answer so it can help others. Not seeing the solution in the answer section.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install sonar scanner first

```
brew install sonar-scanner
```

Comment: I already have sonar-scanner installed. but it is still not working for me

Comment: @FahedYasin did you find the solution?